# MultipleOutputs with AWS EMR S3

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mapreduce, amazon-emr

I have this job where I write the output using multiple outputs. This program gives output with normal Hadoop Cluster.

But when I use AWS cluster, and give s3n paths for the multiple outputs as shown below, I do not get any output in the s3n path specified. Can anyone help me with this?

```
Configuration config3 = new Configuration();
JobConf conf3 = new JobConf(config3, t1debugJob.class);
conf3.setJobName("PJob3.7 scalability test correct 60r");
conf3.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
conf3.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
conf3.setMapOutputKeyClass(StockKey.class);
conf3.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);   
conf3.setPartitionerClass(CustomPartitionerStage3.class);
conf3.setOutputValueGroupingComparator(StockKeyGroupingComparator.class);
conf3.setOutputKeyComparatorClass(StockKeySortComparator.class);
conf3.setReducerClass(dt1Amazon.class);
   //conf3.setNumMapTasks(10);
conf3.setNumReduceTasks(30);
conf3.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
conf3.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf3, new  Path(other_args.get(2)),TextInputFormat.class, PMap3aPos.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf3, new  Path(other_args.get(1)),TextInputFormat.class, PMap3b.class);
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(conf3,"s3n://gs3test/output/MIDPairspos/pairfile", TextOutputFormat.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class);
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(conf3,"s3n://gs3test/output/MIDpos/idfile", TextOutputFormat.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class);                               
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf3, new Path(other_args.get(3)));                 
JobClient.runJob(conf3);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hum, looks like missing authentication on S3... Did you define this in your configuration file?

<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>s3://BUCKET</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId</name>
  <value>ID</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
  <value>SECRET</value>
</property>

Comment: Access Key and Access Secret are set. I figured out the problem. The custom partitioning, grouping and sorting are not happening as specified in the job conf. Don't know why its happening and how to fix it.